# what is T or K in java

Tags: java, generics

i understand when i need to deal with collection i should go with generics , but there are many time i have seen classes defined with generics . i am not able to see why should i define my class with generics

```
public class MyClass<T> {
....
}
```

i tried to see everywhere but everyone castdown to collections , so is class with generics to be defined only if i am planning to use that class with collection or classes with generics are POJO only. helper class or util class with generics are of no use .

Comment: "helper class or util class with generics are of no use."  ...No?

Answer (score 3):

A simple example of using generics outside a Collection is the Comparable interface.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 0):

Generics allow you to work with any type of object, rather than just specifying one type of object that your class can handle. It makes your class more general.

Read more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/

For example, you could create a custom LinkedList implementation that could created LinkedLists to store any type of object (or primitives using wrapper classes). That would look like this:

```
 public class MultiPurposeList<T> {
        //class definition
 }
```